# Managing tabs in a ttk.Notebook (enabling, disabling, etc.)

Tags: python, ttk

I'd like to know how to change the state of a tab in a ttk.Notebook after it's creation and how to manage multiple tabs properly.

Example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
from myWidgets import Widget1, Widget2, Widget3

def enableTabs(notebook):
    tabs = notebook.tabs()
    for i, item in enumerate(tabs):
        item['state'] = 'enabled' #This doesn't work
        item.configure(state='enabled') #Doesn't work either
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)

    w1 = Widget1()
    w2 = Widget2()
    w3 = Widget3()

    notebook.add(w1, text='tab1', state='disabled')
    notebook.add(w2, text='tab2', state='disabled')
    notebook.add(w3, text='tab3', state='disabled')

    enableTabs(notebook) #This would be called upon certain events in the real     application

    root.mainloop()
```

In this example I use disable - enable but in general I'd like to be able to change certain settings all at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you call `item` is just an identifier (a float), which doesn't have a `state` key or a  `configure` method. Also, the possible values for a tab's state in this context are `normal`, `disabled` and `hidden`, not `enabled`. Try this instead:

```
for i, item in enumerate(tabs): 
    notebook.tab(item, state='normal') # Does work
```

Comment: My bad I thought the tabs() returned a list of actual tab objects not an identifier. Your answer is perfect thanks.